# I have a pandas data frame, with a bunch of strings i want to know if i can use optimization algorithms on it

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, query-optimization

```
 code   clus_0  clus_1  clus_2
0   5   AASP_2  CCOD_1  0
1   6   AASP_2  EXTR_1  AASP_2
2   7   BBOP_2  BBOP_1  NSRS_1
3   8   DGSP_1  DVEN_1  AASP_5
4   9   DDTR_1  AASP_4  AASP_2
```

the data frame has this structure but is much longer, and a wanted to aplly an optimization algorithm on it, but i can't fathom how i could do it, since they are not numbers. I want to pick one of each row making my pick the most diverse, is it possible?

I've tried to make some kind of table with code as index, and the "clus" as the columns, so it would be 1 if it had a matching code and 0 if it didnt but i sill couldnt make much of it

Comment: The question is a bit vague, what would be an expected output? An unwanted output? What exact operation do you want to run on it?

Comment: my problem is that each code is for one of the stores of my company, and each of the clus are competitors that were clusterized, for each store of mine i wanted to pick a competitor to do a search, i think that this is an otimization algorithm problem since there are parameters to be optimized like i want to visit the maximum of competitors. did this clear up my question?

Comment: It gives context, but the question is still missing focus (i.e. a specific programming issue you want to solve). Anyway, check my answer below for the "*it would be 1 if it had a matching code and 0 if it didnt*" part and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont think it works for me, sorry of my inexperience, but i dont think i know how to tacle it, i tought that making a table with code as index, and columns as all possible "clus" and mark them 1 if they corespond in my exemple table and 0 if they dont. that way i would have a binary combination to probably plug in an optimization library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign 1 if the value is not unique you could [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) the code column and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then apply [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and restore the original format with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
(df.set_index('code').stack()
   .duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
   .unstack().reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   code  clus_0  clus_1  clus_2
0     5       1       0       0
1     6       1       0       1
2     7       0       0       0
3     8       0       0       0
4     9       0       0       1
```